# Angular-js x-editable not populating the editable-number value on page load

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, x-editable

I have x-editable form with two fields editable-text and editable-number.

```
%form{"editable-form" => "", :name => "editableForm", :onaftersave => "savePaymentDetails()"}
 %table.table.table-striped
   %tr{"ng-repeat" => "obj in bussiness_info.text"}
     %td
       %h6.blue 
       {{ obj.name | camelize}}
     %td{"ng-if" =>"obj.type=='text'"}
       %span{"e-name" => "obj.name", "e-ng-required" => "obj.required", "editable-text" => "obj.value"} {{ obj.value || 'empty' }}
     %td(ng-if="obj.type=='number'")
       %span{"e-name" => "obj.name", "editable-number" => "obj.value", "e-ng-required" => "obj.required","e-step" => "0.01","e-max"=>100} {{ obj.value || 'empty' }}
```

[image]
So,on clicking edit the form should populate both editable-text and editable-number fields if its values are present already.In my case both the fields the has the value,but only the editable-text alone is populated.
[image]

The editable-number is not getting populated with the pre-present value.I am not sure whether this because of any scope issues or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Its my blunder. The typeof both tin_no(editable-text field) and margin(editable-number field) were String.So my editable-number field was not getting populated. Editable-number field got populated after changing the type of margin to Number.